# How to make comments enabled in custom post in discussion section?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom post events in wordpress. I have written as below

```
 $args = array(
 .....
 .....
'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments'),
 ......
 );
```

in function.php file

All the comments are unchecked in all the custom posts's discussion section by default.

I want that all the comments should be checked automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by `All the comments are unchecked`? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yes. I want that comments should checked by default in the discussion section in admin dashboard

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by `discussion section in admin dashboard`. It could be the Discussion meta box or the Comments panel.

Comment: I am sending you a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/5enas80b9n8qlpf/screenshot.jpg